# SQL Server 2008 Trial - How many days left?

Tags: sql-server, licensing

If you have SQL Server 2008 Trial edition installed, how can you find out how many days are left?

It doesn't seem to be in the Help-About dialog, or anywhere obvious.

edit: Ok, so it did turn out to be in Help-About, see answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, in Management Studio, under `Help` > `About`, you'll find what you're looking for.

[(Source)](http://insanesql.blogspot.com/2009/01/evaluation-editiondays-remaining.html)

EDIT: Then there's this one too:

> To check how many days left for your
>   trial version you can check out the
>   folder under the following
>   path<>\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log... the
>   creation date of the folder would let
>   you know how long you have been using
>   it. Apart from this, i am not aware of
>   any other places in the DB or server
>   that it is maintained.

[(Source)](http://www.sqldev.org/sql-server-setup--upgrade/2008-trial-days-left-amp-upgrade-to-enterprise-94201.shtml)

Comment: Ah yes, so it was in Help->About, I just had missed it because of the column widths in the grid that displayed the info. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For SQl server you have to use management studio:

Help menu --> About --> Now you will see something like this

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Complete (expires in 127 days)  10.0.2531.0

Comment: Ah yes, so it was in Help->About, I just had missed it because of the column widths in the grid that displayed the info. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you installed licensed SSMS (Client Tools) and Installed Evolution version of SQL Server then it does not works.